# How do I deal with nested mongoose queries and async issues in my one-to-many relationship?

Tags: angularjs, mongoose, one-to-many, mean-stack

I'm trying to query for all posts from a database, and then grab all comments belonging to each post, and send that whole thing back to the front end to display. My strategy thus far has been using nested Mongoose queries (see pseudo-code and actual code examples below), and am getting some unexpected results due to async issues.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong, or if there's a better way to do what I'm trying to accomplish:

### My Schemas:

I have three `Schemas` in Mongoose:

1. UserSchema (`User`)
2. PostSchema (`Post`)
3. CommentSchema (`PostComment`)

I've only included the `CommentSchema` here, to simplify my question:

```
var CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema (
    {
        message: {
            type: String,
            minlength: [2, 'Your comment must be at least 2 characters.'],
            maxlength: [2000, 'Your comment must be less than 2000 characters.'],
            required: [true, 'You cannot submit an empty comment.'],
            trim: true,
        }, // end message field
        userID: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        },
        username: {
            type: String,
        },
        postID: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Post'
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
);
```

When a new Comment is created, the `_id` of the post is recorded into the `.postID` field of the comment.

### My Pseudo-Code Strategy:

```
// query for all posts using a mongoose promise
// run a `for loop` through the array returned posts
    // query my comments collection for any comments pertaining to post[i]
        // attach comments returned to the post[i]
        // push post[i] into a new array (now with comments attached)
        // check if on last run through array
            // res.json the new array back to the front end 
            // On front end just iterate through each post and its contained comments.
```

However, when I attempt this strategy, I get some async issues with my second Mongoose query within the for loop.

### My Actual Code Example:

```
Post.find({}) // first query
    .then(function(allPosts) {
        for (var i = 0; i < allPosts.length; i++) {
            _post = allPosts[i];
            console.log(_post, i);
            PostComment.find({postID: _post._id}) // **nested query
                .then(function(comments) {
                    console.log({
                        post: _post,  // this value will not match the console log above (outside of the query)
                        index_value: i, // this value too will be out of match with the console log above
                        comments: comments,
                    });
                    // attach new comment to allPosts[i]
                    // push post with comment attached to new array
                    // check if on last iteration, if so res.json new array
                })
                .catch(function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                })
         }
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
```

### Issue from Code Example Above:

In the example above, in the second query, the `**nested query`, the value of `i` and `_post` are out of sync by the time the data is returned from the mongoose promise (the `.then`). The for loop is progressing faster than the data is being returned. Thus, if I try and attach any comments to the parent post object (`_post`), the variable is already out of synch with the progression of the for loop (`_post` now becomes the next post in the array). I'm stumped on how to remedy this and get all my comments from each post, and bundle this together for the front end. I'm just confused at this point.

### Desired Behavior:

I want a populated list of all my posts, with the comments attached to each post, to make iterating over them on the front end easier. That way on the front end, all posts are shown with their respective comments beneath them.

### Conclusion:

What am I doing wrong? How can I iterate through all of my posts, and grab all the comments for each, and make it tidy for front-end display in Angular? Is my approach wrong or too "costly" in my queries? Is there a better way to achieve my desired behavior?

Any insight or help is **beyond** appreciated! I searched around hoping to see another question like this, and have been hitting my head on this issue for awhile =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to accomplish this. I did have to make some changes to my Schemas. Because Mongo does not allow for joins, we can instead use the `populate()` Mongoose method (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

Keeping this explanation short, I wanted to show the updated Schemas, and then show how I was able to populate across just one level. At the bottom of this post is another example, showing how to populate across multiple levels.

### UserSchema:

```
// Setup dependencies:
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Setup a schema:
var UserSchema = new Schema (
    {
        username: {
            type: String,
            minlength: [2, 'Username must be at least 2 characters.'],
            maxlength: [20, 'Username must be less than 20 characters.'],
            required: [true, 'Your username cannot be blank.'],
            trim: true,
            unique: true, // username must be unique
            dropDups: true,
        }, // end username field
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
);

// Instantiate our model and export it:
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

### PostSchema:

```
// Setup dependencies:
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Setup a schema:
var PostSchema = new Schema (
    {
        message: {
            type: String,
            minlength: [2, 'Your post must be at least 2 characters.'],
            maxlength: [2000, 'Your post must be less than 2000 characters.'],
            required: [true, 'You cannot submit an empty post.'],
            trim: true,
        }, // end message field
        user: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        },
        comments: [{
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Comment'
        }],
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
);

// updates userID based upon current session login info:
PostSchema.methods.updateUserID = function(id) {
    this.user = id;
    this.save();
    return true;
};

// adds comment to post's comments array:
PostSchema.methods.addComment = function(commentID) {
    this.comments.push(commentID);
    this.save();
    return true;
};

// Instantiate our model and export it:
module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

### CommentSchema:

```
// Setup dependencies:
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Setup a schema:
var CommentSchema = new Schema (
    {
        message: {
            type: String,
            minlength: [2, 'Your comment must be at least 2 characters.'],
            maxlength: [2000, 'Your comment must be less than 2000 characters.'],
            required: [true, 'You cannot submit an empty comment.'],
            trim: true,
        }, // end message field
        user: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        },
        _post: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Post'
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
);

// Assigns user ID to comment when called (uses session info):
CommentSchema.methods.updateUserID = function(id) {
    this.user = id;
    this.save();
    return true;
};

// Assigns post ID to comment when called:
CommentSchema.methods.updatePostID = function(id) {
    this._post = id;
    this.save();
    return true;
};

// Instantiate our model and export it:
module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

### Solution: Use the Populate Method:

Using the `populate()` method (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) we can start with our Post model and populate the `comments` field.

Using the instance methods defined in the PostSchema, we push comment ID's into the `Post.comments` array, which the `populate()` method below grabs all comment objects and replaces the IDs with the actual comment objects.

```
var User = require('mongoose').model('User');
var Post = require('mongoose').model('Post');
var PostComment = require('mongoose').model('Comment');

Post.find({})
    .populate('comments')  // populates comments objects based on ids in `comments`
    .exec()
    .then(function(commentsAndPosts) {
        console.log(commentsAndPosts);
        return res.json(commentsAndPosts);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.json(err);
    })
```

The link provided to Mongoose's documentation has a nice clean example.

Now, on the front end, each post object has a comments array inside, and all comment objects have been populated! Sweet!

### Overview:

I was able to store an array of comment IDs inside each Post object (when a new comment is made, the `comment._id` is pushed into the `Post.comments` array). Using `populate()`, we can query into the Comments collection and grab all comment objects associated with the relevant ID. This is great, as after our populate method completes, we can send back our entire array of all posts and comments as one JSON object, and iterate over them on the front-end.

### Populating at Multiple Levels:

Let's say in the above scenarios, I wanted to also get the username for both post and comment authors (note: each comment and post object has a `user` field which stores a `User._id`.

We can use populate, by nesting some parameters, to reach across multiple levels as follows. This will delivers the same data as the example above (all posts and all comments), but includes the usernames for both comments and posts based on the stored user id:

```
Post.find({}) // finds all posts
    .populate('user') // populates the user (based on ID) and returns user object (entire user object)
    .populate({ 
        path: 'comments', // populates all comments based on comment ID's
        populate: {  path: 'user' } // populates all 'user" fields for all comments (again, based on user ID)
    })
    .exec()
    .then(function(commentsAndPostsWithUsers) {
        console.log(commentsAndPostsWithUsers);
        return res.json(commentsAndPostsWithUsers);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    })
```

In the above example, we start by grabbing all posts, and then grab all user objects for each post, and then all comments, along with each user object for each comment, and bundle it all up!

### Iterating Through on Front-End with Angular:

We can iterate through our returned posts using `ng-repeat`**:

```
<!-- Repeating Posts -->
<div ng-repeat="post in commentsAndPostsWithUsers >
    <h3 ng-bind="post.user.username"></h3>
    <h2 ng-bind="post.createdAt"></h2>
    <p ng-bind="post.message"></p>
    <!-- Repeating Comments -->
    <div ng-repeat="comment in post.comments">
        <h4 ng-bind="comment.user.username"></h4>
        <h5 ng-bind="comment.createdAt"></h5>
        <p ng-bind="comment.message"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

** Angular controller not shown in code example above.

We can access the username for posts or comments via, `post.user.username` or `post.user.username`, respectively, as the entire user object has been attached (thus why we have to navigate down to get the username). We can then use another `ng-repeat` to iterate through `post.comments`, showing all of the comments. Wishing the best and hope this helps someone avoid the confusion I did!